# Android AsyncHttpClient onSuccess() with global arrayList

Tags: java, android, rest, arraylist, asynchttpclient

I have a global arrayList which I am using for showing android cardViews

```
ArrayList<Transaction> listTransactions;
```

When using listTransactions.add inside onSuccess of AsyncHttpClient it works fine, but out of onSuccess function (inside initializeAdapter) the listTransactions becomes empty

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getTransactions();
    initializeAdapter();
}

private void initializeAdapter(){
    Transaction_Adapter adapter = new Transaction_Adapter(listTransactions);
    transaction_card.setAdapter(adapter);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    transaction_card.setLayoutManager(llm);
    transaction_card.setHasFixedSize(true);
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(transaction_card.getContext(),1);
    transaction_card.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
}

public void getTransactions() {
    listTransactions=new ArrayList<>();
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(ip,params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                if(obj.getBoolean("status")){
                    int count = obj.getInt("count");
                    for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
                        JSONObject o = obj.getJSONObject("Transaction_" + i);
                        listTransactions.add(new Transaction(o.getInt("Sender"),o.getInt("Receiver"),o.getDouble("Amount"),o.getString("Date"),o.getString("Type")));
                    }
                    //testing 
                    for(Transaction t:listTransactions){
                        Log.e("transaction",String.valueOf(t.type)); //this shows the type of all transactions correctly
                    }
                }
            .
            .
            .
            }
        }//catch & onFailure...
    });}
```

There is no exception or errors.

Also When I try to add it manually before the initializeAdapter(), it shows the manually added card fine

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getTransactions();
    listTransactions.add(new Transaction(1,2,111,"01-12-2016 12:15","test")); //manually added card
    initializeAdapter();
}
```

Comment: you defiuned `listTransactions=new ArrayList<>();` in `getTransactions` function, how can you expect to use it outside in `initializeAdapter`?

Comment: I defined it global ArrayList<Transaction> listTransactions;
That was the initialization

Comment: :D sorry, my mistake. i think you should set adapter first then initialize your array. that's the right way.

Comment: I've tried but still nothing, the problem is that onSuccess seems like it doesn't change global variables, I even tried to put "response" inside a global String variable and still nothing, it only shows it inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onSuccess is not yet executed when you call initializeAdapter(), because it is asynchronous. You should initialize your adapter onSuccess or notifyDataSetChanged() after adding the elements in the ArrayList.

Comment: Add transaction_card.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged() in your onSuccess after adding all elements in the listTransactions ArrayList.

Comment: it works when I added the initialize inside onSuccess.
Thanks

Comment: You're wellcome ;)